# Bring the linear part of a ODE system into a diagonal form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> > Consider the system 
> >     $$
> > \dot{x}=y,\quad\dot{y}=z,\quad\dot{z}=-x-y-z+x^2+az^3.
> > $$
> >     Check that the zero equilibrium has a pair of pure imaginary eigenvalues. Make a linear coordinate transformation which makes the linear part of the system block diagonal.

First, the linearization matrix at $(0,0,0)$ is
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\-1 & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=-1,\lambda_2=-i,\lambda_3=i$.

**Edit due to Did's help**

The transformation matrix is 
$$
S=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\-1 & 0 & -1\\1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
With this, we get
$$
S^{-1}MS=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=:J
$$

So the aim is to transform the system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{y}\\\dot{z}\end{pmatrix}=M\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x^2+az^3\end{pmatrix}~~~(1)
$$
into the system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{u}\\\dot{v}\\\dot{w}\end{pmatrix}=J\cdot\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}f(u,v,w)\\g(u,v,w)\\h(u,v,w)\end{pmatrix}~~~(2).
$$
How do I get from system (1) to system (2)?

Do I have to compute
$$
S^{-1}MS \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}+S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x^2+az^3\end{pmatrix}S?
$$
This would give me the system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{u}\\\dot{v}\\\dot{w}\end{pmatrix}=J\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(u^2+aw^3)\\\frac{1}{2}(u^2+aw^3)\\-\frac{1}{2}(u^2+aw^3)\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: The block corresponding to the eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$ should not read $$\begin{pmatrix}i & 0 \\0 & -i\end{pmatrix}
$$ but $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$ So *the aim is to bring the system into* the form
$$
\dot{u}=v+f(u,v,w),\quad\dot{v}=-u+g(u,v,w),\quad\dot{w}=-w+h(u,v,w).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your determination of $S$ is now correct.

In order to transform system (1) into system (2), multiply with $S^{-1}$ *from the left* and use that $SS^{-1}$ gives you the identity matrix:
$$
S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{y}\\\dot{z}\end{pmatrix}=S^{-1}MS\cdot S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}+S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x^2+az^3\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, set
$$
\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}:=S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}
$$
and what you get is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{u}\\\dot{v}\\\dot{w}\end{pmatrix}=J\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}+S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x^2+az^3\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Finally to get rid of the $x$- and $z$ terms in the last summand, use that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=S\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The result is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{u}\\\dot{v}\\\dot{w}\end{pmatrix}=J\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\cdot ((u-v)^2+a(u+v)^3)\\\frac{1}{2}\cdot ((u-v)^2+a(u+v)^3)\\-\frac{1}{2}\cdot ((u-v)^2+a(u+v)^3)\end{pmatrix}
$$
so you've got your transformed ODE-System.